# QPixmap fromImage results in Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, segmentation-fault, qimage

I'm at a complete loss here...

I'm trying to convert a QImage to a QPixmap but my program keeps crashing with the following stack trace. What's weird is it works fine if the QRectF that I specify doesn't have an upper left point of (0, 0). I know QImage has a copy method as well, but that was also failing (with no useful stacktrace), so I figured I'd try to work with Pixmaps instead... Line's 4/5 of the stacktrace are mine, but I'm basically doing the following

```
QImage _drawing = QImage(1024, 1024);
// fill _drawing with some data

QRect i_work = QRect(1, 1, 10, 10);
QRect i_break = QRect(0, 0, 10, 10);

QPixmap foo = QPixmap::fromImage(_drawing);
// QPixmap good = foo.copy(i_work); // I work
QPixmap broken = foo.copy(i_break); // Segmentation fault...
```

StackTrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x01f44024 in QBasicAtomicInt::ref (this=0xabababab)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_i386.h:120
120     ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_i386.h: No such file
 or directory.
        in ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_i386.h
(gdb) bt
#0  0x01f44024 in QBasicAtomicInt::ref (this=0xabababab)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_i386.h:120
#1  0x01964d3e in QImage::QImage (this=0x28cc70, image=...)
    at image\qimage.cpp:1125
#2  0x01990682 in QRasterPixmapData::fromImage (this=0xc391a00,
    sourceImage=..., flags=...) at image\qpixmap_raster.cpp:151
#3  0x019862ab in QPixmap::fromImage (image=..., flags=...)
    at image\qpixmap.cpp:2031
#4  0x00423fdc in TxImage::getSelection (this=0xc3b6cb0, selection_area=...)
    at TxImage.cpp:207
#5  0x004421e2 in RomView::mouseReleaseEvent (this=0xc397978, event=0x28d5fc)
    at RomView.cpp:261
#6  0x019241a0 in QWidget::event (this=0xc397978, event=0x28d5fc)
    at kernel\qwidget.cpp:8187
#7  0x01c9e6bc in QFrame::event (this=0xc397978, e=0x28d5fc)
    at widgets\qframe.cpp:557
#8  0x01d2bf0f in QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent (this=0xc397978,
    e=0x28d5fc) at widgets\qabstractscrollarea.cpp:1043
#9  0x01e9aae6 in QGraphicsView::viewportEvent (this=0xc397978,
    event=0x28d5fc) at graphicsview\qgraphicsview.cpp:2862
#10 0x01f86a13 in QAbstractScrollAreaPrivate::viewportEvent (this=0xc3969f8,
    event=0x28d5fc) at widgets//qabstractscrollarea_p.h:100
#11 0x01f8506c in QAbstractScrollAreaFilter::eventFilter (this=0xbfa7388, o=
    0xbf43978, e=0x28d5fc) at widgets//qabstractscrollarea_p.h:116
#12 0x6a1ffc73 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters (
    this=0xa7a46d8, receiver=0xbf43978, event=0x28d5fc)
    at kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp:847
#13 0x018d96e5 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper (this=0xa7a46d8,
    receiver=0xbf43978, e=0x28d5fc) at kernel\qapplication.cpp:4392
#14 0x018d7909 in QApplication::notify (this=0x28fe34, receiver=0xbf43978,
    e=0x28d5fc) at kernel\qapplication.cpp:3959
#15 0x6a1ff9dc in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal (this=0x28fe34,
    receiver=0xbf43978, event=0x28d5fc) at kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp:732
#16 0x01f4d53e in QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent (receiver=0xbf43978,
    event=0x28d5fc)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.h:218
#17 0x018d6118 in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent (receiver=0xbf43978,
    event=0x28d5fc, alienWidget=0xc3adb70, nativeWidget=0x28fd60,
    buttonDown=0x237941c, lastMouseReceiver=..., spontaneous=true)
    at kernel\qapplication.cpp:3056
#18 0x0193fc63 in QETWidget::translateMouseEvent (this=0x28fd60, msg=...)
    at kernel\qapplication_win.cpp:3317
#19 0x0193aaa6 in QtWndProc (hwnd=0x130fb8, message=514, wParam=0,
    lParam=5373956) at kernel\qapplication_win.cpp:1657
#20 0x762c62fa in USER32!OffsetRect () from C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
#21 0x900010c2 in ?? ()
#22 0x90909090 in ?? ()
#23 0x00df7d80 in operator+ ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

I assure you that qatomic_i386.h exists and looking at line 120...

```
112: inline bool QBasicAtomicInt::ref()
113: {
114:     unsigned char ret;
115:    asm volatile("lock\n"
116:                 "incl %0\n"
117:                 "setne %1"
118:                 : "=m" (_q_value), "=qm" (ret)
119:                 : "m" (_q_value)
120:                 : "memory");
121:    return ret != 0;
122: }
```

Comment: QBasicAtomicInt doesn't matter, because the value of this passed to it is already invalid. This indicates that QImageData, d in QImage is not initialized. I looked at all constructors of QImage, and they all initialized d, so its strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was successfully able to solve the problem, but I'm not sure of the underlying problem, as the workaround doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to me.

So I was rendering the `QImage` on a `QGraphicsScene`/`QGraphicsView`. I had my `QImage` at location (0,0) on the scene and another `QGraphicsItem` also at location (0,0). Removing the other `QGraphicsItem` from the scene before calling copy on the `QImage` seemed to fix the problem. I've no idea what's so special about the point `(0,0)`. The only thing I can think of is that `isNull` on a `QPoint(0,0)` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to tell what is going on. However QT Doc for [QImage constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#QImage-3) says that

> Warning: This will create a QImage
>   with uninitialized data. Call fill()
>   to fill the image with an appropriate
>   pixel value before drawing onto it
>   with QPainter.

Ensure that your QImage is filled properly by calling fill () method. Maybe this is the cause of the problem.